# javascript boolean variable's value is not changing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a variable called `itemExist` and set that equal to false. My goal is to set this variable's value to true if a condition happens. My code is this:

```
var itemExist = false;

        user.findById({_id: decoded._id}).populate('shoppingCart').exec((err, items)=>{
            items.shoppingCart.forEach(async item=>{
                if(item.productId == productId){
                    itemExist = true;
```

When I console log the itemExist variable outside of all theese functions

```
console.log(itemExist);
```

I get that result on the console:

> false

But it should be true. How can I solve this problem, what is causing that?

Comment: Javascript are async, so, try to put console inside the promise. If works, there's no problem, just a little confusion on your execution plan...

Comment: Console is logging before the async calls complete.

Answer (score 0):

Perform your work inside `exec` function

```
user.findById({_id: decoded._id}).populate('shoppingCart').exec((err, items)=> 
    {
        const itemInArr = items.shoppingCart.find(item => item.productId === productId);
        //!! - convertation to boolead value
        itemExist = !!itemInArr;
        console.log(itemExist);
    }
);
```